# Ruby on rails created_at format show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added a `time` method to my `application_helper.rb`.

I want to show in view `<%= message.created_at %>` exist, how can I use relative type instead of  `<%= message.created_at %>` to display such as 2 minutes ago, 1 week ago

```
def relative_time(start_time)
  diff_seconds = Time.now - start_time

  case diff_seconds
  when 0 .. 59
    puts "#{diff_seconds} seconds ago"
  when 60 .. (3600-1)
    puts "#{diff_seconds/60} minutes ago"
  when 3600 .. (3600*24-1)
    puts "#{diff_seconds/3600} hours ago"
  when (3600*24) .. (3600*24*30) 
    puts "#{diff_seconds/(3600*24)} days ago"
  else
    puts start_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not use [***`time_ago_in_words`***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) ?

Comment: Remove all the puts from the code above and it should work. BTW, rails already have a helper called `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` -  you might wanna check if that's suits you.

Comment: @Pavan - Oh, that's cool. When did they added alias for this ridiculus name I've mentioned above?

Comment: @BroiSatse Don't know :)

Comment: <%= time_ago_in_words(message.created_at) %> ago. I added this one and it worked, I want to add more feature to this, what I want to do is, if it is more than 7 days, I want normal date not 8 days ago, how can I implement?

Comment: @YunusHatipoglu: have your own helper which will call `time_ago_in_words` if < 7 days or display the date otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already is a method for this called `time_ago_in_words` (Thanks Pavan for mentioning this alias, I always used `distance_in_time_in_words_from_now`). To change the way sentences are displayed, you need to configure your locales:

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      half_a_minute: half a minute
      less_than_x_seconds:
        one: less than 1 second
        other: less than %{count} seconds
      x_seconds:
        one: 1 second
        other: '%{count} seconds'
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one: less than a minute
        other: less than %{count} minutes
      x_minutes:
        one: 1 minute
        other: '%{count} minutes'
      about_x_hours:
        one: about 1 hour
        other: about %{count} hours
      x_days:
        one: 1 day
        other: '%{count} days'
      about_x_months:
        one: about 1 month
        other: about %{count} months
      x_months:
        one: 1 month
        other: '%{count} months'
      about_x_years:
        one: about 1 year
        other: about %{count} years
      over_x_years:
        one: over 1 year
        other: over %{count} years
      almost_x_years:
        one: almost 1 year
        other: almost %{count} years
```